# What is the format of the 'date' field in global-messages-db.sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, thunderbird

I'm a Thunderbird user, and I'm using the self-contained .sqlite file (**global-messages-db.sqlite**) to develop some sql scripts, I'm trying to make sense of the different objects inside this database, and there's the `message` table which has the column `date`  but it does not seem as a date string, it shows me a bunch of numbers.

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT a.c1subject AS "SUBJECT",
       a.c3author AS "FROM",
       a.c4recipients AS "TO",
       b.date,
       c.folderURI AS "FOLDER_LOCATION",
       c.name AS "FOLDER_NAME"       
    FROM messagesText_content a
    INNER JOIN messages b ON a.docid=b.id
    INNER JOIN folderLocations c ON b.folderID=c.id
    WHERE a.c1subject LIKE ('Chunk of text%');
```

Here's the date result retrieve by the query:

1547902246000000

1547823370000000

1547651729000000

What could be the meaning of this? could this be because some configuration? how can I convert this string to a human readable date?

Note: I also used sqllite3 command directly from the command line to check this row and I have the same result.

any advice is appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE: in order to convert the epoch format to a human readable date I used this query on my SQLite database with the `STRFTIME` function:

```
 SELECT a.c1subject AS "SUBJECT", STRFTIME('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',DATETIME(SUBSTR(b.date,1,10)-18000, 'unixepoch')) AS "DATE"
 FROM messagesText_content a, messages b, folderLocations c 
 WHERE STRFTIME('%d/%m/%Y',DATETIME(SUBSTR(b.date,1,10), 'unixepoch')) > 'DD/MM/YYYY' 
 AND a.docid=b.id 
 AND b.folderID=c.id 
 AND a.c1subject = ('YOUR_TEXT)') 
 ORDER BY b.date DESC;
```

The `-18000` parameter is used to substract 5 hours, because a particular server configuration.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is likely in seconds since epoch. There should be many sites that should help you convert it. For example, you can try this site to convert your dates:

https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Thanks you @rcode74 I'll check the page to see if it makes sense comparing the date with the Thunderbird interfeace

Comment: Yep it makes sense, I'll check if its possible to perform the convesion in batch because my query retrieves more than 1000 rows